# Splitting a CSV string but not certain elements javascript

Tags: javascript, string, csv, split

If given an comma separated string as follows

```
'UserName,Email,[a,b,c]'
```

i want a split array of all the outermost elements so expected result

```
['UserName','Email', '[a,b,c]']
```

string.split(',') will split across every comma but that wont work so any suggestions? this is breaking a CSV reader i have.

Comment: split it at commas and detect the cases where to reintegrate. option b: write your own (stateful) split method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 similar answers, so might as well make it a 3rd instead of referring you there. It's a stateful split. This doesn't support nested arrays, but can easily made so.

```js
var str = 'UserName,Email,[a,b,c]'

function tokenize(str) {
  var state = "normal";
  var tokens = [];
  var current = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    c = str[i];

    if (state == "normal") {
      if (c == ',') {
        if (current) {
          tokens.push(current);
          current = "";
        }
        continue;
      }
      if (c == '[') {
        state = "quotes";
        current = "";
        continue;
      }
      current += c;
    }
    if (state == "quotes") {
      if (c == ']') {
        state = "normal";
        tokens.push(current);
        current = "";
        continue;
      }
      current += c;
    }
  }
  if (current) {
    tokens.push(current);
    current = "";
  }
  return tokens;
}


console.log(tokenize(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by matching the string to this Regex:

```
 /(^|(?<=,))\[[^[]+\]|[^,]+((?=,)|$)/
```

```js
let string = '[a,b,c],UserName,[1,2],Email,[a,b,c],password'
let regex = /(^|(?<=,))\[[^[]+\]|[^,]+((?=,)|$)/g
let output = string.match(regex);
console.log(output)
```

The regex can be summarized as:

**Match either an array or a string that's enclosed by commas or at the start/end of our input**

The key token we're using is **alternative** `|` which works as a sort of *either this, or that* and since the [regex engine is eager](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), when it matches one, it moves on. So if we match and array, then we move on and don't consider what's inside.

We can break it down to 3 main sections:

- `(^|(?<=,))`

  - `^` Match from the beginning of our string
  - `|` Alternatively
  - `(?<=,)` Match a string that's preceded by a comma without returning the comma. Read more about positive lookaround [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
- `\[[^[]+\] | [^,]+`

  - `\[[^[]+\]` Match a string that starts with `[` and ends with `]` and can contain a string of one or more characters that **aren't** `[`

    - This because in `[1,2],[a,b]` it can match the whole string at once since it starts with `[` and ends with `]`. This way our condition stops that by removing matches that also contain `[` indicating that it belongs the second array.
  - `|` Alternatively
  - `[^,]+` Match a string of any length that doesn't contain a comma, for the same reason as the brackets above since with `,asd,qwe,` technically all of `asd,qwe` is enclosed with commas.
- `((?=,)|$)`

  - `(?=,)` Match any string that's followed by a comma
  - `|` Alternatively
  - `$` Match a string that ends with the end of the main string. Read [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for a better explanation.